# nginx reverse proxy to https?

Tags: express, nginx

This is my config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name prettylogs.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name prettylogs.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass  https://localhost:9200/;
        }
}
```

When I visit prettylogs.com, I do get redirected to https://prettylogs.com, however the request never reaches my node server from nginx. If I go to the port directly, the node server is running and displays.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, is there any reason to have SSL overhead in localhost connections?

Comment: Not that I can think of. My issue is that I'm using nginx to replace a simple node proxy, and my proxy before handed the ssl stuff off to my main express app. Since nginx is handling the ssl itself, I should probably switch my express app to not use ssl, yeah?

Comment: It depends. May be ssl overhead doesn't worth efforts to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be problem with your nginx conf file.

```
proxy_set_header   Host             $proxy_host;
```

it should have

```
proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
```

try with this updated configuration, your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Tried that. No change. Here's my nginx.conf file: https://gist.github.com/Jorenm/7b918c303ff2f71952c2

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that both ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key were required to get this working for me. I didn't see this mentioned anywhere, so there might be some setting which negates this, but this fixed it.